# Issues matching zero-byte using grep

Tags: shell, grep, gnu-coreutils

I'm trying to find 7zip version 3 file headers in a file. According to the [documentation](https://7-zip.org/recover.html) they should look like this:

```
00: 6 bytes: 37 7A BC AF 27 1C        - Signature 
06: 2 bytes: 00 04                    - Format version
```

So I constructed this grep command which should match them:

```sh
grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text $'7z\xBC\xAF\x27\x1C\x00\x03'
```

Yet it also matches the string ending in `0000`:

```sh
% xxd -p -r <<< "aaaa 377a bcaf 271c 0000 bbbb 00 377a bcaf 271c 0003" | grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text $'7z\xBC\xAF\x27\x1C\x00\x03'
2:7z'
13:7z'
```

The output I expect to have is just `13:7z'`

Comment: `\x00` it's not possible to pass zero byte as part of argument

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is it because it gets interpreted by the shell? Is it impossible to match zero-bytes with grep? Are you saying there is no solution at all?

Comment: `Could you elaborate?` Yes. `Is it because it gets interpreted by the shell?` No, it's because of how C language was invented. Nowadays I would say: because "historical reasons". `Is it impossible to match zero-bytes with grep?` No, it's possible. `Are you saying there is no solution at all?` No.

Comment: That's what I meant by "interpreted by the shell" $'string' instructs the shell to convert the escape sequences into their literal representations and then pass them to grep, which then triggers the issue with strlen. But thank you. 

Comment: Well, it's really before that, because shell calls `execve` and `execve` takes zero terminated strings. So it's really before even `grep` is executed. But with "strlen" it's easy to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to pass zero byte as part of an argument. Because a string ends with zero byte in `C`, so `grep` when running `strlen(argv[...])` will not "see" anything after zero byte.

If there are no newlines in regex, you could use `--file=`.

```
xxd -p -r <<< "aaaa 377a bcaf 271c 0000 bbbb 00 377a bcaf 271c 0003" |
LC_ALL=C grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text -f <(
    echo -n 7z;
    echo BCAF271C0003 | xxd -r -p
)
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Non_002dASCII

Alternatively use PERL regex

```
xxd -p -r <<< "aaaa 377a bcaf 271c 0000 bbbb 00 377a bcaf 271c 0003" | 
LC_ALL=C grep --only-matching --byte-offset --binary --text -P '7z\xBC\xAF\x27\x1C\x00\x03'
```

When dealing with binary, remember to disable UTF-8 sequences handling with locale setting `LC_ALL=C`.

Note: `<<<""` and `$'string'` are not available in any shell - they are available in bash.